# ¿Cómo imprimir sólo los atributos de una clase hija de un vector de la clase padre?

Tags: java, poo

Ahora mismo tengo estas 4 clases.

Una es la clase padre, `Vehiculo` que tiene todos los atributos que tienen todos los vehículos y que comparten entre ellos, y tiene el método `getDatos` abstracto.

Luego tengo la clase `Moto` y `Coche` hijas que cada una de ellas tienen sus propios atributos y el método `getDatos` que imprime los atributos compartidos con la otra clase hija y los suyos propios.

Y esta es mi clase `Taller` donde tengo el vector `vehiculos`.

```
public class Taller {
    private Vector<Vehiculo> vehiculos;

    public Taller() {
        this.vehiculos = new Vector<Vehiculo>();
    }

    public void registrarVehiculo(Vehiculo v) {
        vehiculos.add(v);
    }

    public void imprimirVehiculos() {
        //Imprime todos los vehiculos
        for(Vehiculo v: vehiculos)
            System.out.println(v.getDatos());
    }

    public void imprimirVehiculos(String clase) {
        if(clase=="Moto") {
            //Imprimir solo los que sean motos
        }else {
            if(clase=="Coche") {
                //Imprimir solo los que sean coches
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En el método `ImprimirVehiculo(String clase)` si en el `main` al introducir un vehículo que por ejemplo es un coche, ¿Cómo hago para que solo me imprima aquellos que son solo coches?

Una forma que probé para que funcione fue la de hacer 2 vectores, uno para coches y otro para motos, pero yo lo que quiero es que con un solo vector de la clase padre pueda imprimir los atributos de cualquiera de las dos de las clases hijas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > ¿Como imprimir solo los atributos de una clase hija de un vector de la clase padre?

Para poder imprimir el contenido del objeto de tipo `Moto` o `Coche`, podríamos crear 2 métodos en la clase `Taller`. Un método que se encargue de imprimir los datos del objeto `Moto` y el otro para que imprima el contenido del objeto `Coche`.

Ejemplo:

```
class Taller 
{
    private Vector<Vehiculo> vehiculos;

    public Taller() 
    {
        this.vehiculos = new Vector<Vehiculo>();
    }

    public void registrarVehiculo(Vehiculo v)
    {
        vehiculos.add(v);
    }

    public void imprimirVehiculos() 
    {
        //Imprime todos los vehiculos
        for(Vehiculo v: vehiculos)
            System.out.println(v.getDatos());
    }

    public void imprimirCoche()
    {
        for(Vehiculo v: vehiculos)
        {
            if(v instanceof Coche)
                System.out.println(v.getDatos());
        }
    }

    public void imprimirMoto()
    {
        for(Vehiculo v: vehiculos)
        {
            if(v instanceof Moto)
                System.out.println(v.getDatos());
        }
    }

}
```

La palabra clave `instanceof` te permite comparar si el nombre de una clase es igual a otra clase. Es decir, si la variable `v` hace referencia a un objeto de tipo `class Moto`, se lo compara con `class Moto`.

Sin embargo, si tuviera más clases hijas como camión, bicicleta, entre otros. Se gastaría mucho código, debido a que, por cada subclase, debería de crear un nuevo método. Por lo tanto, esos dos métodos lo pudiéramos reducir a esto:

```
    public  void imprimirVehiculos(String nameClass)
    {
        for(Vehiculo v : vehiculos)
        {           if(v.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(nameClass))
                System.out.println(v.getDatos());
        }
    }
```

La forma de usarlo sería de esta forma:

```
public class Program
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Taller t = new Taller();
        Moto mot = new Moto();
        Coche coh = new Coche();

        t.registrarVehiculo(new Moto());
        t.registrarVehiculo(new Coche());
        t.registrarVehiculo(new Moto());


        t.imprimirVehiculos("Moto");
        System.out.println("");
        t.imprimirVehiculos("Coche");
    }
}
```

**Observación:**

La forma como lo estabas haciendo si funcionaría; sin embargo, igual gastarías mucho código:

```
public void imprimirVehiculos(String clase)
{   
    if(clase == "Moto") 
    {
        for(Vehiculo v: vehiculos)
        {
            if(v instanceof Moto)
                System.out.println(v.getDatos());
        }
    }
    else if(clase=="Coche") 
    {
        for(Vehiculo v: vehiculos)
        {
            if(v instanceof Coche)
            System.out.println(v.getDatos());
        }
    }

}
```

En este caso usar la siguiente expresión:

```
clase =="Coche"
```

No sería peligroso y te lo compruebo de esta forma:

```
public class Program
{
    static void me(String n)
    {
        if(n == "Coche")
        {
            System.out.println("Coche");
        }
        if(n == "Moto")
        {
            System.out.println("Moto");
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        me("Coche");
        me("Moto");
    }
}
```

Ambas condiciones dará verdadero e imprimirá el mensaje `Coche` y `Moto`.

**¿Por qué sucedió esto?**

La razón principal es por el [String Pool](https://www.journaldev.com/797/what-is-java-string-pool) (es el bloque de memoria donde se guardan las cadenas literales).

Cuando se llame el método `me` (la primera vez), el JVM se encargará de crear un objeto de tipo `String` y lo guardará en el StringPool, debido a que, no se encuentra la cadena `Coche` en el pool.

Luego cuando el método `me` empiece a ejecutar sus instrucciones, nos encontraremos con la siguiente línea:

```
if(n == "Coche")
```

Daría verdadero, porqué el JVM no creará otro objeto de tipo `String`, debido a que, la cadena `Coche` ya se encuentra en el StringPool, por lo tanto, se estaría comparando las mismas referencias.

**¿Cuando daría un error inesperado?**

Si hiciera algo como esto:

```
    public  void imprimirVehiculos(String nameClass)
    {
        for(Vehiculo v : vehiculos)
        {           if(v == nameClass)
                System.out.println(v.getDatos());
        }
    }
```

Esta línea te dará un error lógico en tu programa:

```
if(v == nameClass)
```

Porqué la variable `v` y `nameClass` hacen referencia a objetos diferentes. Así que debes tener mucho cuidado en como utilizar el operador `==` al momento de comparar referencias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el metodo `getClass()` acompañado de `getSimpleName()` para obtener el nombre de la clase a la que estas accediendo.

Te he hecho un ejercicio de prueba para que veas como utilizarlo:

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vehiculo lista [] = new Vehiculo[4];

        int contadorCoche = 0;
        int contadorMoto = 0;

        lista[0] = new Coche();
        lista[1] = new Coche();
        lista[2] = new Moto();
        lista[3] = new Moto();

        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {

            if(lista[i].getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("Coche")) {

                contadorCoche++;            
            }
            else if(lista[i].getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("Moto")) {

                contadorMoto++;
            }           
        }

        System.out.println("Coches: " + contadorCoche);
        System.out.println("Motos: " + contadorMoto);

    }
}
```

Y esta seria la salida del programa:

```
Coches: 2
Motos: 2
```

Como opcion puedes cambiar esto: `.equalsIgnoreCase("Coche")` por `== "Coche"`

Comment: Me sale bien pero solo cuando pongo uno es decir que si pongo lo de if(vehiculos.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("Coche")) y nada mas si me salen solo los coches y viceversa, pero cuando pongo los dos con un else if me aparecen todos aunque haya puesto que solo me aparezcan los coches

Comment: Imagino que tienes el vector de tipo `Vehiculo`. ¿Que instancia estas guardando en el vector? ¿estas creando un `new Vehiculo` o un `new Coche/Moto`?